# SFML Pixel manipulation - changing the size of single character in window

Tags: c++, sfml

Is there any way to change the size of single pixel in window, because i would rather work on single console characters that are 8x8 pixels not 1x1.

Comment: The best option is to use RectangleShape.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to scale up (or down) everything in a window, the easiest way would be to changing the window's `sf::View` by calling `sf::RenderWindow::setView()`:

```
sf::RenderWindow myWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Test");

// Define a view that's 320x240 units (i.e. pixels) in size and is centered at (160, 120)
sf::View myView(sf::Vector2f(160, 120), sf::Vector2f(320, 240));

// Apply the view
myWindow.setView(myView);
```

After running this code, everything rendered to the window will be upscaled by a factor of 2 (since you're showing 320x240 within 640x480). In a similar way you could achieve a scaling factor of 8, e.g. by making your window (800, 800) and setting your view to (100, 100).

However, depending on what you render, you won't get a pixelated look.

If you'd like to create pixel art with sharp/upscaled pixels, I'd recommend simply rendering your scene to a render texture of the desired resolution and then rendering that texture to the actual window, upscaled (and with disabled filtering):

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Scaling", sf::Style::Default);

    // Set the view to upscale
    // Use 1/8th of the window's size
    sf::View view(sf::Vector2f(50, 37.5f), sf::Vector2f(100, 75));
    window.setView(view);

    // Let's create a render texture as buffer
    // (I'm skipping error checking for simplicity)
    sf::RenderTexture buffer;
    buffer.create(100, 75); // Again 1/8th of the window size

    sf::Sprite bufferSprite(buffer.getTexture());

    // Something to draw
    sf::CircleShape circle(20, 6);
    circle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Transparent);
    circle.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Black);
    circle.setOutlineThickness(2);
    circle.setOrigin(20, 20); // Move origin to center

    // Let's use a simple sf::Clock to animate a bit
    sf::Clock timer;

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            }
        }

        // Rotate the circle
        circle.setRotation(timer.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() / 10);

        // Clear the scene in the render texture
        buffer.clear(sf::Color(64, 127, 192));

        // Draw our circle
        circle.setPosition(25, 37.5f); // Despite the float offset, the result will be pixel accurate!
        buffer.draw(circle);

        // Finish the render texture drawing
        buffer.display();

        // Draw the render texture's contents
        window.draw(bufferSprite);

        // Let's render the upscaled shape for comparison
        circle.setPosition(75, 37.5f);
        window.draw(circle);

        // Display the results
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Once compiled, this will result in two spinning six sided "circles", one pixelated (by the render texture's resolution) and one sharp (due to simple upscaling):

[image: Example program running.]

Comment: I can't upvote this enough. It's a simple solution that works absolutely flawlessly. Great answer!